# Jboss crashes frequently

Tags: java, linux, jboss

I have a Java EE application running on jboss-4.0.4.GA in linux. Previously I have allocated 2 GB memory but the jboss crashed and the memory was full. Now I have increased the memory to 8 GB but still same problem. Still the jboss crashes because of full memory.

What can be the cause for it because I think memory isn't the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the logs show you something useful that you could add to your question? please add also some information about your OS, your Java enviroment details and about how many applications are deployed in this jboss instance

Comment: add the server log here

Comment: You can monitorize memory management with JVisualVM. It's included with JDK